# When babel processes async / await code does it bundle unrelated calls?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

Is babels `async` / `await` code smart enough to see the code below:

```
async function alpha () {
  let resultOne = await processNumber(5)
  let resultTwo = await processNumber(5 + 8)
  let resultThree = await processNumber(resultOne.number)
  let resultFour = await processNumber(resultOne.number + resultThree.number)
  return resultFour
}
```

As something like the following, where the first two promises within this function can happen together because the values needed to perform those operations does not need to wait for anything.

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

async function beta () {
  let {resultOne, resultTwo} = await Promise.props({
    resultOne: processNumber(5),
    resultTwo: processNumber(5 + 8)
  })
  let resultThree = await processNumber(resultOne.number)
  let resultFour = await processNumber(resultOne.number + resultThree.number)
  return resultFour
}
```

I would understand the `alpha` function as waiting for each async function call before it moves on to the next, where in `beta` `resultOne` and `resultTwo` are happening simultaneously, this is only possible because they don't need to wait on any other calls. I was wondering if this was truly the case or if babel does something behind the scenes to bundle these together.

Comment: "smart enough to see the code below" --- it is smart enough to not see that. Those two examples are different and there is really no problem to implement `processNumber` so that 2 code samples returned different results.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a benchmark between the two and it seems it does not account for this on it's own.

Here's the test:

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'

async function processNumber (int) {
  await Promise.delay(500)
  return {number: int + 3}
}

async function alpha () {
  let resultOne = await processNumber(5)
  let resultTwo = await processNumber(5 + 8)
  let resultThree = await processNumber(resultOne.number)
  let resultFour = await processNumber(resultOne.number + resultThree.number)
  return resultFour
}

async function beta () {
  let {resultOne, resultTwo} = await Promise.props({
    resultOne: processNumber(5),
    resultTwo: processNumber(5 + 8)
  })
  let resultThree = await processNumber(resultOne.number)
  let resultFour = await processNumber(resultOne.number + resultThree.number)
  return resultFour
}

async function main () {
  const TEST_ALPHA = 'test alpha'
  const TEST_BETA = 'test beta'

  console.time(TEST_ALPHA)
  let resultAlpha = await alpha()
  console.log(resultAlpha)
  console.timeEnd(TEST_ALPHA)

  console.time(TEST_BETA)
  let resultBeta = await beta()
  console.log(resultBeta)
  console.timeEnd(TEST_BETA)

  return true
}

main()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Here's the results:

```
thomasreggi@zx:PAS-api$ babel-node test.js 
{ number: 22 }
test alpha: 2025ms
{ number: 22 }
test beta: 1508ms
true
thomasreggi@zx:PAS-api$ babel-node test.js 
{ number: 22 }
test alpha: 2033ms
{ number: 22 }
test beta: 1511ms
true
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS it is nearly impossible to make any strict statements whether a given expression is "unrelated" to another arbitrary expression (especially statically).

It happens because due to its highly-dynamic nature almost every expression may cause hidden (or not so hidden) side effects that may break the expected flow of the program.

For your very code it is really easy to break the code in case if both "unrelated" calls are triggered "simultaneously":

```
let isFirst = true;

async function processNumber(v) {
    await Promise.delay(2000 - v * 100);

    if (v < 10) {
        if (!isFirst) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }

    isFirst = false;

    return { number: v + 3 };
}
```

This would work for `alpha`, but throw for `beta`.

If you know it would be fine and want to run them "in parallel" just use `await`s correspondingly:

```
async function alpha () {
  let one = processNumber(5)
  let two = processNumber(5 + 8)

  const resultOne = await one;

  let resultThree = await processNumber(resultOne.number)
  let resultFour = await processNumber(resultOne.number + resultThree.number)
  return resultFour
}
```

Also note, that the `resultTwo` is not used anywhere in your code.